# What is the correct use of DryIoc with ASP.NET WebApi AND HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dryioc

**UPDATE**

After upgrading DryIoc to the most recent version we now get some more indication on what is going on:

```
2021-07-14T20:32:08.6994870Z ERROR MyClass: Database error in Report Processing DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.ContainerIsDisposed;
message: Container is disposed and should not be used: "container with ambient DryIoc.AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext with scope {Name=~WebRequestScopeName}
 with Rules  with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments} has been DISPOSED!
```

This makes total sense now: we are using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem()` to queue a background task from a HTTP request, which has a HTTP context container setup for it by DryIoc. The lifetime of that container depends on the lifetime of the HTTP request, with the background task being 'orphaned' (for want of a more correct word). We can reproduce this problem easily now by introducing a delay in the background task so that it executes after the HTTP request is fulfilled (AKA, end request).

It is not entirely clear how we rectify this in a 'correct' manner - I looked through the documentation and could not find how to handle this situation. What I did find that works was to create a new `MyClass` instance using the root container to resolve the injections. Pseudo code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(RootContainer.Resolve<Lazy<ClassA>>());

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct => await myClass.DoTask().ConfigureAwait(false));
```

The question is whether this is the 'correct' manner in which to go about this - that is, this may work now but can it have side effects? Comments appreciated.

**ORIGINAL**

I am introducing DryIoc into an existing ASP.NET WebAPI project. I use the following container setup and then the registers (omitted):

```
IContainer container = new Container(rules => rules.With(FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments));
container = container.WithWebApi(config, throwIfUnresolved: type => type.IsController());
```

This all works as expected.

However, we also use the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()` to queue background work at the end of certain WebApi calls. This has led to the following error being reported by that background work item:

```
2019-08-13T20:53:36.5792777Z ERROR LAPTOP XXX.Models.SomeModel [/] (): Error in Report Processing DryIoc.ContainerException: Container is disposed and should not be used: "Container with ambient ScopeContext DryIoc.AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext without Scope
 with Rules  with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments} has been DISPOSED!
 You may include Dispose stack-trace into the message via:
container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())"
   at DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3)
   at DryIoc.Container.ThrowIfContainerDisposed()
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, Type requiredServiceType, Request preResolveParent, Object[] args)
   at (Closure`2 )
   at FastExpressionCompiler.LightExpression.ExpressionCompiler.CurryClosureFuncs.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`2.<Curry>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at XXX.Models.SomeModel.GetReporting(Int32 pid, Int32 oid, Int32 uid, Int32 peid) in C:\src\XXX\XXX\Models\SomeModel.cs:line 2277
```

On debugging, it is found that the (lazy) injected variable is null. On a hunch I caused this lazy variable to be resolved prior to the call to `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()`:

```
_ = diVariable.Value;
```

and the background task is successful as the dependencies are present.

HOWEVER, I am not sure whether this is the correct thing to do, and whether it will be problematic later on. What is the correct use of DryIoc with ASP.NET WebApi AND `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem()`?